# Express redirect before Angular app loads

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport-saml

**Case**
When I visit my url `https://example.com/` my angular application loads and the url adds the hash-routing to `https://example.com/#/`. My angular code checks for user credentials from a saml url and doesn't find anything, so it calls passport login which then takes me to my SAML login page (company hosted) which returns me back to my homepage again with the proper user details.

My question is around being able to prevent angular app from loading and doing a `req.user` check on all my application routes in **express** before doing my app.get(*) catch all to send over the index.html page.

Is this possible with client side routing? Here is a look at the server.js as configured right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var env = require('dotenv').config();
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('./server/sso/passport')(app);

// Enforce HTTPS on all requests
app.enable('trust proxy');
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] === 'https') {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
  }
});

// Set Up
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// All responses return CORS allowed
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers.origin) { res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin); }
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,OPTIONS");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
  ('OPTIONS' == req.method) ? res.send(200) : next();
});

// API Routes
app.use(require('./server/routes/book-routes'));
app.use(require('./server/routes/car-routes'));

// SSO
app.use(require('./server/sso/routes')(passport));

// Serve the client website.
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')));

// Route all unhandled requests to index.html, so client's router can handle them.
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  var authenticated = req.user;
    if (authenticated) {
      res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist', 'index.html'));
    } else {
      res.redirect('/samlLogin', 301);
    }
});

// Start server on the specified port and binding host
app.listen(appEnv.port, appEnv.bind, function () {
  // Print a message when the server starts listening.
  console.log("Serving taas-tools app at " + appEnv.url);
});

// Export the app and listener.
module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else was running into this issue: the default cacheProvider setup by passport-saml is a memory cache. My issue was that I was running multiple instances of the server. So A would redirect to B and not have stored the req.user or any req.session information. I changed my bluemix configuration to 1 instance and it worked. Cheers~